# Not able to create tables in hbase

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have installed hbase in my local ubuntu vm , which already have hadoop running in psuedo distribution mode.Hadoop version is 3.1.2 and hbase version is 2.1.2.

i'm able to get the hbase shell but when try to create a table  get the following error:

```
hbase(main):001:0> create 'test', 'data'

ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.PleaseHoldException: Master is initializing
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.checkInitialized(HMaster.java:2969)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.createTable(HMaster.java:1972)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterRpcServices.createTable(MasterRpcServices.java:630)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.protobuf.generated.MasterProtos$MasterService$2.callBlockingMethod(MasterProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:413)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:324)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:304)
```

on further investigation i found this error in the regionserver logs

```
2019-02-12 06:21:21,484 ERROR [RS_OPEN_META-regionserver/ubuntu:16020-0] handler.OpenRegionHandler: Failed open of region=hbase:meta,,1.1588230740
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.asyncfs.FanOutOneBlockAsyncDFSOutputHelper
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.asyncfs.AsyncFSOutputHelper.createOutput(AsyncFSOutputHelper.java:51)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.AsyncProtobufLogWriter.initOutput(AsyncProtobufLogWriter.java:167)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.AbstractProtobufLogWriter.init(AbstractProtobufLogWriter.java:166)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.wal.AsyncFSWALProvider.createAsyncWriter(AsyncFSWALProvider.java:113)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.AsyncFSWAL.createWriterInstance(AsyncFSWAL.java:612)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.AsyncFSWAL.createWriterInstance(AsyncFSWAL.java:124)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.AbstractFSWAL.rollWriter(AbstractFSWAL.java:756)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.AbstractFSWAL.rollWriter(AbstractFSWAL.java:486)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.AsyncFSWAL.<init>(AsyncFSWAL.java:251)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.wal.AsyncFSWALProvider.createWAL(AsyncFSWALProvider.java:73)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.wal.AsyncFSWALProvider.createWAL(AsyncFSWALProvider.java:48)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.wal.AbstractFSWALProvider.getWAL(AbstractFSWALProvider.java:152)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.wal.AbstractFSWALProvider.getWAL(AbstractFSWALProvider.java:60)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.wal.WALFactory.getWAL(WALFactory.java:284)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.getWAL(HRegionServer.java:2104)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.handler.OpenRegionHandler.openRegion(OpenRegionHandler.java:284)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.handler.OpenRegionHandler.process(OpenRegionHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.executor.EventHandler.run(EventHandler.java:104)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

are these two related , Can somebody provide a solution for this please
this is my hbase-site.xml

```
<configuration>
        <property>
      <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
      <value>hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase</value>
   </property>

   <property>
      <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
      <value>/home/bithu/hbase-temp</value>
   </property>

  <property>
      <name>hbase.master.port</name>
      <value>7000</value>
   </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.regionserver.port</name>
      <value>7010</value>
   </property>

   <property>
      <name>hbase.tmp.dir</name>
      <value>/home/bithu/hbase-temp/tmp</value>
   </property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.unsafe.stream.capability.enforce</name>
  <value>false</value>
</property>
   <property>
     <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
     <value>true</value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Hbase does not support Hadoop 3 last time I checked. Thus `NoClassDefFoundError`

Comment: I tried to switch to Hadoop 2.9.2, the result is still same, do I need to downgrade HBase?

Comment: You can refer to the table here. And looks like is has been updated for Hadoop 3 now. https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#hadoop 

But anyway, `NoClassDef` still means you are missing some library, and `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io` package would be a problem with Hbase, not Hadoop

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue running Hbase-2.1.5 on top of Hadoop 3.1.3.

Adding below property in hbase-site.xml would solve this issue.

```
<property>
   <name>hbase.wal.provider</name>
   <value>filesystem</value>
</property>>
```